# auto increment a field called "revision count" when I change the field called "ETA". how is this possible?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have a list which collects ETA from user in the field called "ETA". I need to know how many times the ETA field is changed  by user. I wanted the count to be tracked in the field called "revision count". How is it possible through SP workflow?

Answer (score 0):

While you can trigger your workflow whenever an item in the list is modified, Out of the box, SharePoint Designer workflows have no way of telling which field in that item was changed.  But, with a little trickery, you can make it work.

Add a hidden column to the list named `previousETA`.  Make sure it is hidden so that end users cannot update this value on their own.  Mark your workflow to trigger whenever an an item in the list is updated.  As a first step in the workflow, check if the value of `previousETA` equals `ETA`, if so, then the workflow doesn't need to do anything.  If the values are different, then use the item update action in the workflow to set `previousETA` equal to the new `ETA`, then increment your "revision count field".

The following blog post is taking a similar approach to update a bunch of task items when someone [changes the End Date on a item in the Project list](https://www.c5insight.com/Resources/Blog/tabid/148/entryid/722/use-sharepoint-workflow-to-determine-if-a-field-changed-without-code.aspx).

To increment a value in a column, you first have to use the "Do Calculation" action, to add 1 to the "revision count" value found in the current item, then you can use the "Update Item" to save the new value back to the item.  The screenshot below calculates the new value, then saves it in the same Update action that also copies the ETA value.
[image]

Comment: Thanks Willman. I am understanding the logic. But I am facing difficulties in implementing it as I don't know what is the sequence of steps to be followed in the designer. I am trying something but getting struck in the +1 increment calculation. Would be great if you could help with steps or screenshot. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to use the "Do Calculation" action to "Add 1" to the revision count.  I have updated my answer with the explanation and a screenshot that includes the dialog from the Update item action.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the effort. I am able to create workflow without any errors. However, the field "Revision Count" is not getting auto populated with incremented number and "previousETA" is not getting auto filled with the date (copy of ETA). Pls guide.

Comment: Unfortunately, SharePoint Designer Workflows don't provide much diagnostic information in the Workflow History, so you'll have to help it out.  Before your "IF" check, use a Log to History action to log both the current ETA and the currently saved "previousETA" values.  Then immediately after the step where you calculate  the new revision count (but before your Update Item action), do another Log to History the current value of the item's revision count, and the variable that holds the new revision count.  After than, run your workflow again, and lets see what shows up in that run's history.

Comment: Hurray!!! it started working. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry to hijack this thread. can you pls help with this query as well. https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/275113/workflow-to-revert-a-person-field-to-original-name-when-changed-to-some-other-na