# Workflow to revert a person field to original name when changed to some other name and also email the original name user

Tags: sharepoint-designer

Basically my requirement is this:

Employee creates an entry with his manager name in the "Manager" field and Skip level manager name in the "Skip Manager" field.
Later, When he attempts to change the "skip Manager" it should be reverted to original name and also send an email to Manager name marked in "Manager" field.
However, his manager mentioned in "Manager" field should be able to modify the "skip Manager" field.

Pls help with workflow for this. This is my first workflow attempt. So would be great if detailed steps are provided to help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

- Add a hidden user field "Original Skip Manager" to the list
- When an item is created, have a workflow that copies the value of "Skip Manager" into "Original Skip Manager"
- When an item is updated, have a workflow that checks if the Modified By user is the same as the Manager user
- If **yes**, do nothing (Manager is allowed to make edits)
- If **no**, *then* check to see if "Skip Manager" is different than "Original Skip Manager"
- If "Skip Manager" and "Original Skip Manager" are different, set "Skip Manager" to be the value of "Original Skip Manager"

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am new to SP designer and struggling to convert these steps in to workflow. Would you mind providing the screenshots or steps/actions as given in the designer?

Comment: Gentle reminder.

Comment: @Sai, What is being suggested here for the "Skip Manager" field is nearly identical to what you just did for your "ETA" field in https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/274633/auto-increment-a-field-called-revision-count-when-i-change-the-field-called-e/274636.  The big difference here is that you are also going to do an IF 'Not Equals' compare between the `Current Item:Skip Manager` field and the `Current Item:Modified By` and within that conditional block perform another check between `Current Item:Skip Manager` and `Current Item:Previous Skip Manager`