# Checker Notification

Tags: 2013, workflow, sharepoint-designer-workflow

I have a List contains multiple column. among all there are two column. Maker and Checker. If maker add checker name then checker should get an email once with the required information. this email should not float to him everytime on adding or editing row. only once when his name got added.

condition if checker name got change the new checker should get email.

need to done this via workflow via SPD13. please help.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new column, similar to `checker` and name it as `old checker`

Kindly have the below 2 if conditions in your SPD workflow. the below is not the exact coding format of SPD designer, kindly use the below logic in your workflow.

```
if(checker is not null and Old Checker is null) //first time if the checker field is populated
{
  send email to checker;
  set old checker = checker;
}

if(checker is not equal to Old Checker)//if new checker is added to the item.
{
  send email to checker;
  set old checker = checker;
}
```

Make the workflow to run on item create and item update event.

**EDIT**

As mentioned by @Willman, make sure to make `old checker` hidden in the edit, display, new form and list view, so that the end user will not know this value.

Comment: Make sure you make `old checker` hidden, otherwise you can pretty much guarantee that your end users will end up changing that value and screwing up your logic.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint Designer workflow does not have any direct mechanism to tell you which Columns were changed when triggered -- however, there is a technique to work around that.  You can see the [technique in an earlier answer I made for a similar issue](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/274633/auto-increment-a-field-called-revision-count-when-i-change-the-field-called-e/274636#274636).

In short, you need to add a hidden column to the list named `oldChecker`.  Make sure that column is not visible to end users to accidentally update.  In your workflow, you use a `If any value` action to see if the current `checker` field is non-empty and if it is different than `oldChecker`.  If it is different, then you need to send your email notification to the new `checker` user, then in the same workflow update `oldChecker` to match the new `checker`.  That way, the next time the workflow is triggered by an update, if the two values are identical, then you don't need to send your email.